# The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am getting following error when I am trying to split data into train and test. I know that error is occurring because for stratify parameter I should pass categorical data only, not numeric  but here `OFFENSE_CODE` is  like a category except the categories in it are represented by number. So how can I do stratify sampling by `OFFENSE_CODE`.

```
x = df.loc[:,['YEAR','MONTH','DAY_OF_WEEK']]
X_train, x_test, Y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(x,df['OFFENSE_CODE'],stratify=df['OFFENSE_CODE'],random_state=2,test_size=0.3)
```

this is sample of dataset

```
INCIDENT_NUMBER  OFFENSE_CODE               OFFENSE_CODE_GROUP  \
  I192067438           613                          Larceny   
  I192067437          3831  Motor Vehicle Accident Response   
  I192067435          3115               Investigate Person   
  I192067434          3301                  Verbal Disputes   
  I192067433          3301                  Verbal Disputes   

                 OFFENSE_DESCRIPTION DISTRICT REPORTING_AREA SHOOTING  \
                LARCENY SHOPLIFTING       A1            112      NaN   
                    PROPERTY DAMAGE       A1                     NaN   
                 INVESTIGATE PERSON      C11            336      NaN   
                     VERBAL DISPUTE      E18            492      NaN   
                     VERBAL DISPUTE      D14            769      NaN   

  OCCURRED_ON_DATE  YEAR  MONTH DAY_OF_WEEK  HOUR    UCR_PART  \
2019-08-25 19:55:02  2019      8      Sunday    19    Part One   
2019-08-25 18:20:00  2019      8      Sunday    18  Part Three   
2019-08-25 20:45:00  2019      8      Sunday    20  Part Three   
2019-08-25 20:32:00  2019      8      Sunday    20  Part Three   
2019-08-25 20:30:00  2019      8      Sunday    20  Part Three   

      STREET        Lat       Long                     Location      CODES  
WASHINGTON ST  42.355123 -71.060880  (42.35512339, -71.06087980)   tyer613a  
        NaN  42.352389 -71.062603  (42.35238871, -71.06260312)  tyer3831a  
  NORTON ST  42.306265 -71.068646  (42.30626521, -71.06864556)  tyer3115a  
   DERRY RD  42.265933 -71.113774  (42.26593347, -71.11377415)  tyer3301a  
 PARSONS ST        NaN        NaN     (0.00000000, 0.00000000)  tyer3301a
```

i also tried

```
y = df.loc['OFFENSE_CODE'].apply(str)

X_train, x_test, Y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(x,y,stratify=y,random_state=2,test_size=0.3)
```

it is giving same error

ValueError:The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert the column to string and then do the sampling

```
df['OFFENSE_CODE'].apply(str)
```

Dont foget to assign the result back

```
df['OFFENSE_CODE'] = df['OFFENSE_CODE'].apply(str)
```

Comment: ValueError:The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.

Comment: means, you have one offense code which has only 1 value. That obviously cannot be stratified and that will mess up your model also. Better you can exclude it, or copy paste it (boosting) for few more times and then try it.

Comment: yes.. but one of the 222 unique values, has only one data sample. which means lets say for example offence code "613" has only one value. then it cannot be stratified

Comment: df['OFFENSE_CODE'].value_counts() showed that there are indeed some values which occurred only once. OK got it thanks.